# how to replace '\' with '/' in python string

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace a python string that contains a number of `'\'`:

```
String = 'A\BBC\CCB\:ABC'
goal = 'A/BBC/CCB/:ABC'

num = String.count('\')
String.replace('\','/')
```

But I keep getting error message:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Please escape your backslashes with a backslash, i.e. `'A\\BBC\\CCB:ABC'.replace('\\', '/')`.

Answer (score 2):

The \ character in python has special uses. Eg. "\n" (newLine Character). In order to replace it in a string, you need to use one of the following:

```
String.replace('\\','/')
String.replace(r'\','/')
```

The "\" will look for the "\" character.
The r'\' will look for the raw interpretation of the string '\'

Comment: Hey Daniel, for some reason it still doesn't work even I added 'r'

Comment: @thegeek when you are defining your string, make sure it is being defined with the same formatting as well. String = r'A\BBC\CCB\:ABC' or String = 'A\\BBC\\CCB\\:ABC'

Answer (score -1):

In your case you can do it like this:

```
string.replace('\\', '/', num)
```

Comment: Neither you nor OP makes use of the `num` parameter ... what does this add to the previous answer?

Comment: I used `num` parameter as the third parameter to the `replace()` function. This is what I tried to showcase with my anwser.

Comment: I see that much.  I do not see how that applies to the posted problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use '\', consider this situation:

print( "He said: \"Something about her.\"" );

Comment: How is this related to the question? It is not mentioned anywhere about escaping quotes